# Launch Microsoft Remote Assist application from HoloLens app

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, remote-assistance

I want to launch *Microsoft Remote Assist* application from my HoloLens app.
As per my primary research, this is possible via UWP API (LauncherUriAsync method), just by passing my Azure Active Directory Object ID.

Now I am facing two problems...

- When I hit the button from my app to launch remote assist it successfully launchs Remote Assist, but the call is not initiating
  directly though I assigned a specific user's Object ID. (I need to
  hit twice on the person icon to make a call).
- And another problem is when I get back to my app by bloom, my app starts from the
  beginning, which supposes to start from the instance where I left.

Did any one faced this kind of issue?

Answer (score 1):

> when I get back to my app by bloom, my app starts from the beginning, which supposes to start from the instance where I left

Following on @Andrey 's comment, you can use [OnApplicationPause](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationPause.html) in any Unity script to save and restore your app state on suspension of the app. Alternatively, you can try marking your app as *Run In Background* in Unity's *[Player Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsWSA.html#Resolution)*. Keep in mind that that may affect overall system performance and battery use, so I would advice the first option.

> When I hit the button from my app to launch remote assist it successfully launchs Remote Assist, but the call is not initiating directly though I assigned a specific user's Object ID. (I need to hit twice on the person icon to make a call)

Not an expert here at all but it sounds like Remote Assist may not be picking up the object ID from your URI. Maybe try to validate it by entering it from a browser, if that works at all?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know answer to your first question. But for the second problem, you should handle suspend/resume of your app. Docs about app life cycle is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle).